# How to call an api before loading the DOM in Store Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to Execute a function before loading the DOM to fetch the data from an API, I know that in vue it is with before Create but how do I do it in the VUEX store?

Comment: Can’t you just invoke the function in the store directly?

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VueX you execute asynchronous code in "[actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)". So you create an action and call it either from the `beforeCreate` lifecycle hook or wherever you want to put it.

To call an action you can either use `this.$store.dispatch('getMatches')` or you can map an action to your components method block:

```js
methods: {
  ...mapActions([
    'getMatches'
  ])
},
beforeCreate() {
  this.getMatches();
}
```

Usually actions also start with lowercase letters, since they're methods.

Comment: doing it gives me an error, I don't know if I'm doing it wrong

i am doing this:

`import {mapActions} from 'vuex'`

`beforeCreate () {
        ... mapActions (['GetMatches'])
     }`

Comment: You want to be mapping actions to the `methods` object of the Vue component. I've updated my answer.